# PV-diagram: If part of diagram is isotherm is there no work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

Ive filled out this pv-diagram table. Ive done one similar to this diagram , however the other segment c->a was a straight line. In this example its curved.

> > Im wondering if segment c->a is an isotherm? If so, would that mean the work was (-) or zero?

[image]

> > Also in this picture is segment f->d an isotherm?
> >     [image]

Comment: Work on a PV diagram is zero if the volume is constant.  This is not necessarily true for an isothermal process.  For the diagram you drew, the work can be found by the area enclosed by the curve on your graph.

Comment: Exactly. The curves from C to A  and from F to D aren't even isothermes.

Comment: @DavidWhite  Would work be negative for both graphs then C-A and F-D?

Comment: I'm a bit "rusty" on interpreting these graphs, but it looks to me like the top graph (the one with the "isotherm?" label) requires a net input of work into the system, while the other graph (where the arrow appears to go clockwise around the "circuit") does net work on the environment.  I refrain from using the phrase "negative work" and "positive work" because different thermo texts are not totally consistent regarding the sign for work entering or leaving a system.

Answer (score 1):

We can't be sure if a progress is isotherm if we only look at PV diagram without any specific numbers, but we can be sure that the two progresses you listed are not isotherm. Look at it, and you will see that both pressure and volume are decreasing, and according to the equation $PV = nRT$, temperature must also decrease, not stay unchanged.

If you only care about work, I think you should not care about its temperature because you can use the general formula:
$$W = \int_{V_1}^{V_2}{pdV}$$
Let's take the progress c $\to$ a, for example: pressure is always positive, while volume decrease, thus we have negative work.

Note: $W$ denotes the work done by the system during the whole of the reversible process. When $W$ denotes the system take during the reversible process, the formula is $W = -\int_{V_1}^{V_2}{pdV}$.